# Java Swing Sending Navigation Commands Using Arrow Buttons

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings

I need to send navigation commands using JButtons and the keyboard. If the "Up" button/up key is pressed I need to send "Move North" command, if up and left buttons are pressed(from keyboard), I need to send "Move North West" command etc.. The commands should be sent periodically(every 1 second). The following is the code I have.

To explain more,

There are three JButtons on the view. Let's call them jUp, jLeft and jRight. When the user presses the jUp button on the view, the program should send moveNorth commands periodically until the user releases the jUp button. When the user presses the up button on the keyboard, the same thing should happen, and the jUp button should look pressed until the user releases the keyboard up button. When the user presses the keyboard up and left buttons together, the jUp and jLeft buttons should appear pressed until user releases the keyboard buttons. And until user releases the keyboard buttons, a move northWest command should be sent periodically. In the code I have just printed the command using a System.out.println.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class ButtonDemo {
    private JPanel buttons;
    private Timer t;
    private JButton upButton;
    private JButton leftButton;
    private JButton rightButton;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ButtonDemo().run();

    }

    public ButtonDemo() {
        buttons = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        this.t = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (upButton.isSelected() && leftButton.isSelected()) {
                    System.out.println("Move north west");
                } else if (upButton.isSelected() && rightButton.isSelected()) {
                    System.out.println("Move north east");
                } else if (upButton.isSelected()) {
                    System.out.println("Move north");
                } else {
                    t.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    void run() {

        this.upButton = new JButton("Up");
        buttons.add(upButton, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        setupButton(upButton, "Up", KeyEvent.VK_UP);

        this.leftButton = new JButton("Left");
        buttons.add(leftButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        setupButton(leftButton, "Left", KeyEvent.VK_LEFT);

        this.rightButton = new JButton("Right");
        buttons.add(rightButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
        setupButton(rightButton, "Right", KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FrameDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(buttons, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setupButton(JButton button, String key, int vkUp) {
        buttons.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(vkUp, 0),
                key + " pressed");
        buttons.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(vkUp, 0, true),
                key + " released");
        buttons.getActionMap().put(key + " pressed", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setSelected(true);
                pressed(key);
            }
        });

        buttons.getActionMap().put(key + " released", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                button.setSelected(false);
            }
        });
    }

    private void pressed(String key) {
        if (!t.isRunning()) {
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Now for the questions.

a) Even though I call the setSelected method, the button state does not change to pressed. (Visually it doesn't change to pressed state). How can I achieve this?

b) Is there a better/more standard way of achieving this functionality? Using mnemonics/ExecutorService etc..? Am I correct in adding the actions to the "buttons" element's input map. (Is `buttons.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT)` correct?) The panel will be in a tab and the buttons should work when that tab is selected.

Comment: Do you care about the order of the pressed (ie if I press up, then left, then release left, do you care about the fact that the up was first)?

Comment: The order doen't matter. The messages should be sent based on what buttons are pressed right now. As the code in the question works now for the keyboard buttons. And the UI buttons should look pressed based on what keyboard buttons are pressed right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JButton` doesn't have a `selected` state, it has an `armed`.  In order to have a button which maintain a "pressed" state when the mouse or key is released, you must use a `JToggleButton`.

I would, personally, move away from monitoring the button states, personally, and instead, use some kind `enum` or other constants which can be added and removed from a `Set`.  This decouples the means by which the state is achieved from the process that is acting upon the state.

From there, you can use a single `Action` which would be used to notify some kind of observer that the state has changed

[image: Navigation]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.StringJoiner;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public static class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public enum Direction {

            UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT;
        }

        private JToggleButton[] buttons;
        private Set keys;

        private Timer timer;

        private JLabel direction;

        public TestPane() {
            keys = new HashSet();
            direction = new JLabel("Stopped");

            timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (keys.isEmpty()) {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                        direction.setText("Stopped");
                    } else {
                        StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner("-");
                        if (keys.contains(Direction.UP)) {
                            joiner.add("North");
                        }
                        if (keys.contains(Direction.DOWN)) {
                            joiner.add("South");
                        } 
                        if (keys.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                            joiner.add("West");
                        } 
                        if (keys.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                            joiner.add("East");
                        }
                        direction.setText(joiner.toString());
                    }
                }

            });

            Monitor monitor = new Monitor() {
                @Override
                public void pressed(Direction direction) {
                    keys.add(direction);
                    timer.restart();
                }

                @Override
                public void released(Direction direction) {
                    keys.remove(direction);
                }
            };

            MovementAction up = new MovementAction("Up", Direction.UP, monitor);
            MovementAction down = new MovementAction("Down", Direction.DOWN, monitor);
            MovementAction left = new MovementAction("Left", Direction.LEFT, monitor);
            MovementAction right = new MovementAction("Right", Direction.RIGHT, monitor);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 1;

            buttons = new JToggleButton[4];
            buttons[0] = new JToggleButton(up);
            buttons[1] = new JToggleButton(down);
            buttons[2] = new JToggleButton(left);
            buttons[3] = new JToggleButton(right);

            add(buttons[0], gbc);
            gbc.gridy = 2;
            add(buttons[1], gbc);

            gbc.gridy = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            add(buttons[2], gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(direction, gbc);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(buttons[3], gbc);

            addTriggerKeyBindingTo(buttons[0], KeyEvent.VK_UP, KeyEvent.VK_W, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD8);
            addTriggerKeyBindingTo(buttons[1], KeyEvent.VK_DOWN, KeyEvent.VK_S, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD2);
            addTriggerKeyBindingTo(buttons[2], KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_A, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD6);
            addTriggerKeyBindingTo(buttons[3], KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_D, KeyEvent.VK_NUMPAD4);

        }

        protected void addTriggerKeyBindingTo(JToggleButton comp, int... virtualKeys) {
            InputMap im = comp.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = comp.getActionMap();

            for (int key : virtualKeys) {
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key, 0), "trigger");
            }
            am.put("trigger", new AbstractAction() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    JToggleButton button = (JToggleButton) e.getSource();
                    button.doClick();
                }
            });
        }

        protected class MovementAction extends AbstractAction {

            private Direction direction;
            private Monitor monitor;

            public MovementAction(String name, Direction direction, Monitor monitor) {
                putValue(NAME, name);
                this.direction = direction;
                this.monitor = monitor;
                putValue(SELECTED_KEY, false);
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean selected = (boolean) getValue(SELECTED_KEY);
                if (selected) {
                    monitor.pressed(direction);
                } else {
                    monitor.released(direction);
                }
            }

        }

        public interface Monitor {

            public void pressed(Direction direction);

            public void released(Direction direction);

        }

    }

}
```

Now, this example doesn't care, but you could use the `Monitor` to control which key/buttons where triggered at any one time, probably by returning a `boolean` value from `pressed` for example...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm not sure if I can achieve the same thing as now using your method. For example, I need to stop the timer when the user releases all buttons. So I will have to monitor some state, if not the JButton#isSelected. And I don't understand how a queue would make a difference. Also, by associating an Action, I don't think I can check for the pressed and released states separately. And your answer hasn't mentioned how to make the button look pressed when the user presses the corresponding key. It would be really helpful if you can modify my code to show what you mean.

Comment: How can you press more then one button at a time?

Comment: Right now I call setSelected in the actionPerformed method as shown in the code. And I use the isSelected to know if the button is pressed. Right now the code works only using keyboard. I haven't tried using the mouse to press the button. Using the mouse it will always be one button but using the keyboard it can be multiple.

Comment: What is it your are actually trying to achieve?  How would you press more then one button at a time?

Comment: Yes, thanks for the answer +1. I'll wait just to see if someone gives a solution based on JButton before accepting your answer.

Comment: About the only way you could get it work with `JButton` is to take the model from `JToggleButton` and apply to the `JButton`, which just makes it a `JToggleButton` :P